# How does one make a Custom user profile on a per role basis?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

How would you get about assigning a custom profile to a particular role in Drupal 6? For example if the user belongs to a role "TEAM1" and we want them to have a different profile than the rest of the users, how would you get about doing that? The profile must have basic information they can edit however it should also have some fixed fields that pull information from a database.

I am fairly new to Drupal however am a seasoned developer so if you can kindly spend some time explaining it I would greatly appreciate it. I know that one can utilize the Content Profile module however that throws me off a little since I will be pulling some custom data from the database also. I also know that one can make a custom node tpl file however just not sure how it all links together.

Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module.

You'd first create a content type for each type of profile you want (let's say, a content type *teamone* and a content type *profile*). When you edit each content type with Content Profile installed, you can check a box under the *Content profile* fieldgroup: *Use this content type as a content profile for users*.

Now, you'd go to the *Permissions* page, go to the *node* section, and assign the *create teamone content* permission to the *TEAM1* role, and assign the *create profile content* permission to everyone else.

As long as the user doesn't have the *administer nodes* permission, they'd only be able to create one profile or the other, not both.

Comment: That's a problem outside the scope of your question. Check the Drupal [Troubleshooting FAQ](http://drupal.org/Troubleshooting-FAQ) to see how to resolve blank pages.

Comment: sorry to bug you again. I did as you asked me. So what would be the URL to create the custom profile?

Comment: When a user goes to their user profile, a link should show up prompting them to create a new profile. Otherwise, it's the same link as if you were creating a new node: http://example.com/node/add/[contenttype].

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Your method of explaining really helped me as most people assume the simplest of things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You  have quite a lot of paths to follow, expecially if you are ready to write some code.

Here's a good  point to start from: http://drupal.org/node/264556